# Finding a lower bound for an algorithm using the guess/verify method

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I am trying to work out a few guesses on algorithm complexity, but every time I attempt to guess using an exponential time, my guess/verify method seems to fail. I am sure I am doing something absurdly wrong, I just can't find it myself.

For Example, if I have the recurrence **T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 1** , **where T(1) = 0 and T(2) = 1**.

By iterating it a few times and plugging the  vales n=3,4,5,6,7,8... we can observe that for any value of n>=8, T(n) > 2^n, therefore 2^n is not an upper bound.

So, knowing that information I try to guess that T(n)=O(2^n)

T(n) <= C(2^n)

2T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1 <= C(2^n)

2C(2^(n-1))+C(2^(n-2))+1 <= c(2^n)

C(2^n)-C(2^n+2^(n-2)) >= 1

C(-2^(n-2)) >= 1

C >= 1/(2^(n-2)) | as n-> infinity, the expression goes to zero

Wouldn't this mean that my guess is too high? However, I know that that is not the case. Can anyone see where exactly am I butchering the theory? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition from `2T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1 <= C(2^n)` to `2C(2^(n-1))+C(2^(n-2))+1 <= c(2^n)` is wrong.
if `T(n) <= C(2^n)` you can infer that `2T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1 <= 2C(2^(n-1))+C(2^(n-2))+1` but not that `2C(2^(n-1))+C(2^(n-2))+1 <= c(2^n)`.

Note that `2C(2^(n-1))=C(2^n)` so it must be that `2C(2^(n-1))+C(2^(n-2))+1 >= c(2^n)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your algebra is correct after Itay's input, but your understanding of `c >= 1/(2^(n-2))` is wrong.

You're right that as `n --> infinity`, then `1/(2^(n-2)) --> 0`. However, that doesn't mean that `c --> 0`, suggesting that your guess is too high. Rather this suggests that `c >= 0`. Therefore, `c` can be any positive constant and implies that your guess is tight.

Comment: Ahh.. A fellow ND student reviving my 5-year old question :) Sad week after we lost that game. Another reason to go study algorithms (hopefully with Dr. Chen -- I really enjoyed that course)

Comment: Oh hello ND fam! Yes it is a sad week, but it's not the end for us. Funny how you mention Chen, I came across this question while studying for his exam.

Comment: Small world! Best of luck on the exam. That's probably what brought me here 5 years ago as well :)